# text conflict with image clip

Tags: html, css, image

I'm stuck with this part. My image is being `clip-path` but my `class:txt width` won't stretch because of the `img`. I'm sorry if I can't explain it well. English is my 3rd language so I hope you understand the image I attach.

Result

[image]

Actual Image

[image]

```css
    .item1{
 background: url(../img/bg.png);
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 padding-left: 40px;
}

.item1 img{
 float: right;
 -webkit-clip-path: inset(5% 10% 15% 46%);
 clip-path: inset(5% 10% 15% 46%);
 margin-right: -15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.item .txt p{
 text-align: justify;
}

.item .txt h2{
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item1">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YasK2.png">
 <div class="txt">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? You don't want the text stopping at the edge of the image?

Comment: @tshimkus Yes. I want it to go futher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
  .item1 {
      background: url(../img/bg.png);
      background-size: 100%;
      background-repeat: repeat-y;
      padding-left: 40px;
      position: relative;
  }

  .item1 img {
      -webkit-clip-path: inset(5% 10% 15% 46%);
      clip-path: inset(5% 10% 15% 46%);
      margin-right: -15px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
  }

  .txt {
      padding-right: 280px;
  }

  .item .txt p{
      text-align: justify;
  }

  .item .txt h2{
      margin-top: 5px;
      padding-top: 65px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="item1">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YasK2.png">
      <div class="txt">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so maybe something like this if you want to keep the image cropped:
Set your `<div class="item1">` to `position: relative` and `<div class="txt">` to `position: absolute`, then calculate the width of `<div class="txt">` based on the width of the image. (And just in case, maybe set `z-index: 1` or higher on your text div, so it will never appear "behind" the image?)

```
.item1 {
    background: url(../img/bg.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

.item1 img {
    float: right; 
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(5% 10% 15% 46%);
    clip-path: inset(5% 10% 15% 46%);
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.txt {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.item .txt p {
    text-align: justify;
}

.item .txt h2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 65px;
}
```

[Here is a link to a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m1pxhaw/4/)

Answer (score 0):

is this how want it??.. used flex box to place image next to the text and used

```
.item1 img{
 object-fit:cover;
 object-position:center;
}
```

instead of clip-path

https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/rRYPoR

```css
.item1{
    background: url(../img/bg.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    padding-left: 40px;
    display: flex;
}

.item1 img{
 object-fit:cover;
 object-position:center;
}

.item .txt p{
    text-align: justify;
}

.item .txt h2{
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item1">
    
    <div class="txt">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548659979-53d6a343b767?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `clip-path`. I suggest you to use `width, height & object-fit` properties. Which doesn't create a layout issue.

```
.item1 img{
    float: right;
    width: 20%; 
    height: 200px;
    object-fit:cover;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/moorthy-g/pen/NJwomY